# Getting the redirected address after URL.openConnection();

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, caching

First of all I would like to apologise if this question has been asked, I've been Googling but not found any solution.

**URL A: http://graph.facebook.com/1787989776/picture**

**URL B: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/49968_1787989776_350012849_q.jpg**

**In Short**: I want to cache my photo using file name as URL redirected after visiting **URL A**, instead of **URL A**.

**Detailed description:**

We always cache images downloaded. In my case I would like to cache facebook profile's photo. Eg: An image downloaded from **URL A**.

By clicking the link, you can see, we are being redirected to **URL B**.

Caching my photo using **URL A** isn't safe because the image may have changed the next time I call it (user change his profile photo, but Facebook api ease our job by maintaining the graph Url), while my image loader would not be fetching any new image, because the condition "Image is found in cache" gives me true, sure it does.

So, it would be good if I can get the **URL B** and use that to cache my photo.

I believe the description is enough but if you would like to know what I have done here it is:

```
URL url = new URL(imgUrl); // imgUrl = URL A
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile); // downloadedFile = File named with encoded URL A

byte data[] = new byte[10240]; // 10kb
int count;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to HttpClient you can set a [RedirectHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html) with client.setRedirectHandler() which will allow you to get the URL B that URL A redirects to.

Answer (score 0):

```
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + params[0] + "/picture?type=large";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP 
                   || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                   || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
              String URL2 = conn.getHeaderField("Location");                                  
        }
   }
```